# Trying to refresh a console through razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Ok, so I have a console on a page, which gets refreshed through automated jquery, using MVC 3 (razor). When the console gets refreshed, it gets blanked out first (which should not happen when simply appending information). On firefox, this blank out will always return the log with the appended information, but on google chrome, the console stays blanked out.

We did track down a node error "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" code: "3 [Break On This Error] (function(a,b){function cg(a){return d...a:a+"px")}}),a.jQuery=a.$=d})(window);"

Are we missing something or is the automated jquery in error?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't allow submits when the button has "display: none".

The other issue was resolved with a simple mode change.